# Reversing a string using recursion - getting 'Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)' error

Tags: c, function, recursion, reverse, c-strings

I'm trying to reverse a string with the following code but am getting an error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`.

I understand that it's telling me that I'm trying to access a NULL pointer but I fail to see where:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int empty(char s[]){
    return strcmp(s, "") == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}

char getHead(char s[]){
    char *dup = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    strcpy(dup, (s + 0));
    return *dup;
}

char * getTail(char s[]){
    char *dup = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(s) - 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s) - 1; i++){
        dup[i] = s[i+1];
    }
    return dup;
} 

char * ReverseStringHeadTail(char s[]){
    if(empty(s))
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        char head = getHead(s);
        char *tail = getTail(s);
        return strcat(ReverseStringHeadTail(tail), head); // Error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char string[] = "string";
    printf("%s\n", ReverseStringHeadTail(string));

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `ReverseStringHeadTail` either returns `NULL` or calls itself recursively (and then returns what the recursive call returned). Therefore it always returns `NULL`.

Comment: The only function here that's correct is `empty`, and even that could be shortened to `return s[0] == '\0';`.

Comment: `getHead`: `s + 0` is just `s`. That `strcpy` call writes wildly out of bounds. The `dup` pointer is lost, so this also leaks memory. The whole function could be replaced by `return s[0];`.

Comment: `getTail`: The expression `sizeof(char) * strlen(s) - 1` makes no logical sense. If anything, it should be `sizeof(char) * (strlen(s) - 1)`. However, `sizeof (char)` is `1` by definition, so why multiply at all? `strlen(s) - 1` is off by one; you need to allocate `strlen(s)` bytes. The function fails to terminate its result string.

Comment: @jjkl The function empty can be written simpler. For example int empty( const char *s ) { return *s == '\0'; }

Answer (score 0):

The function `empty` can be written simpler.

```
int empty( const char *s )
{
    return *s == '\0';
}
```

The function `getHead` is invalid and does not make sense. 
Its allocates memory for one character but is trying to copy a whole string. And its call results in a memory leak.

You can just write

```
char getHead( const char *s )
{
    return *s;
}
```

The function `getTail` is also invalid. For example if the string is for example `"A"` then the function allocates a memory of 0 bytes. In any case the allocated memory will not contain a string.

The function `strcat` may not be used with an object of the type char or with a null-pointer.

It seems what you mean is the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * ReverseStringHeadTail( const  char *s )
{
    if ( *s == '\0' ) return calloc( 1, 1 );

    char tmp[2] = { *s, '\0' };

    char *p = ReverseStringHeadTail( s + 1 );
    p = realloc( p, strlen( p ) + sizeof( tmp ) );

    return strcat( p, tmp );
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "12345";

    puts( s );

    char *p = ReverseStringHeadTail( s );

    puts( p );

    free( p );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the following

```
12345
54321
```

Pay attention to that the function does not check whether the memory was allocated successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *revm(char *buff, const char *str, const size_t len)
{
    if(!len) len = strlen(str);
    if(!buff)
    {
        buff = calloc(len + 1, 1);
    }
    if(buff && len)
    {
        *buff = *(str + len - 1);
        *(buff + len - 1) = *str;
        if(len > 2) rev(buff + 1, str + 1, len - 2);
    }
    return buff;
}

int main(void)
{

    char *str = "1234567890";

    char *str1 = rev(NULL, str, 0);
    printf("%s\n", str1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

or if you do not want to reverse the string given (it has to be writable)

```
char *rev(char *str, size_t len)
{
    if(!len) len = strlen(str);

    if(len)
    {
        int tmp = *str;
        *str = *(str + len - 1);
        *(str + len - 1) = tmp;
        if(len > 2) rev(str + 1, len - 2);
    }
    return str;
}


int main(void)
{

    char str[] = "123456789";

    char *str1 = rev(str, 0);
    printf("%s\n", str1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```